# oid is there but is not there at PostgreSQL v9.2

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL v9.2.4, at a terminal with psql. When do

```
  \d  pg_class
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM pg_class;
```

**there are NO `oid` column**... But, when do

```
 SELECT oid FROM pg_class;
```

`oid` is there (!!??). It is a bug? Can I use oid in my views without risks?

---

NOTE:
I see that something changed from 9.2 to 9.3 when navigate to
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-class.html
and
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-class.html
because `oid` is  only at 9.3 docs... So v9.2.4 is a kind of "transition", but I think there are also a kind of BUG.

Comment: PS: sorry, only now I see at docs of pg9.3,  "hidden attribute; must be explicitly selected"... But @CraigRinger supply good and supplementar explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oid` is a hidden system column. It is present only on table created `WITH OIDS`, and is never listed in the table columns.

In general, you should consider oids a legacy quirk that these days are just for internal use in the system catalogs. Do not use them in your user tables, and do not create tables `WITH OIDS`.

It is acceptable to refer to them in views over system tables, eg:

```
CREATE VIEW something AS
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class;
```

but in general you should not need to. You can write `oid, *` if you want, but it's not good practice to use `*` in views anyway.

Comment: Thanks. But there are some applications: table audit, complementar table administration, cache control (for tables that are caches) and others.